# Can anyone help me check where is my problem?

Tags: java

Question as bellow:

Write a program to implements an interview scheduler.

These are the requirements for the interview scheduler:

A prompt asks the executive secretary to input the time for the first interview, and then a loop continues to prompt for input of subsequent interview, and then a loop continues to prompt for input of subsequent interview times. Input terminates when the secretary enters a time at or after 5:00 pm. A loop executes pop() operations until the queue is empty. Each iteration outputs the time that the appointment begins, along with the amount of the time available for the director to carry out the interview. When the queue becomes empty, the time for the last interview is the difference between the office-closing time of 5:00 pm. and the prior starting time for the last interview.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;    
import java.util.Date;    
import java.util.LinkedList;    
import java.util.Queue;    
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TimeSchedule {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Queue TimeList = new LinkedList();

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
        df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
        boolean loopstoper = false;
        try {
            Date limit = df.parse("17:00");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String time = scan.nextLine();
            Date date = df.parse(time);
            while (loopstoper == false) {
                if (date.before(limit)) {
                    TimeList.offer(date);
                } else {
                    loopstoper = true;
                    while (TimeList.size() > 0) {
                        System.out.println("Time Schedule = " + TimeList.poll());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

please help me check my work correct or not because it cannot run in Netbean software? Is that answer match that question? Thanks for your helping.

Comment: Pro tip: Select your code and click the "Code Sample" button.

Comment: i try already but don't get that button.

Comment: When you ask questions like this, it's helpful if you can tell us *how* it fails -- not just "it doesn't work".  Do you see an error message? if so, what is it?  Or does the application run, but fail to do what you intended?  How so?  (For example: "The application compiles and runs.  It accepts the user inputs as it's supposed to, but then it just prints out the same date over-and-over, until I force it to quit.").

Comment: Why do you have `df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);`?

Answer (score 1):

Well I copied your code and ran it - right off the bat

```
Date limit = df.parse("17:00");
```

line generated an error until I commented out the

```
df = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.LONG);
```

line.

Next I note that you have a poorly formed loop, you scan in data then start your loop but never scan in anymore data - classic infinite loop.

See what you can do to fix these problems first.  That first error was obvious and should have been found by you easily - if I am going to do your work I should be getting paid for it.

EDIT

Couple of additional comments.  Do you have to use a LinkedList?  Can the times come out of sequence, that is enter in 11am then 10am then 2pm?  I suspect what you want is a simple sortable list - a simple ArrayList would do fine.  Is there a duration parameter - can I enter 11am then 11:01am?  Pretty short interview ;-)

Comment: Sorry about the snarly comment - I just noticed the homework tag.  Still I have pointed you to why its not working - try on your own first - if you are still having problems come back with details and we will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Does this compile and run okay as is? The only thing that I can see that you're missing is the amount of time that the Director has for the current interview. I believer your instructions state that it is simply the difference between the start time of the current interview and the next (unless it's the last interview of the day, in which case use 5:00pm.)